# unique_ptr that contains unique_ptr

Tags: c++, c++14, unique-ptr

*Disclaimer: I at first wrote a version of the question that I thought would be clear but that wasn't at all.  I've reworked it here as a MRE.*

I have the following bit of code:

```
#include <map>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

using std::make_unique;
using std::string;
using std::unique_ptr;

template <typename T>
class Holder {
   public:
    Holder() {}
    ~Holder() {}
   private:
    T value_;  // In real life, we can do something with this.
};

struct Thing {
    Thing() {}
};
class ThingCollection {
   public:
    ThingCollection() {}

   private:
    // In real life, I have more maps of <string, Thing*>.
    // Which is why I use a unique_ptr in the map.
    std::map<string, unique_ptr<Thing>> the_map_;
};
```

My issue is making a `unique_ptr` to a `Holder<ThingCollection>`, which fails due to a missing copy constructor.

```
void foo() {
    Holder<ThingCollection> cm;  // OK.
    auto cmp1 = make_unique<Holder<int>>(Holder<int>());  // OK.
    auto cmp2 = make_unique<ThingCollection>(ThingCollection());    // OK.
    auto cmp3 = make_unique<Holder<int>>(Holder<int>()); // OK.
    auto cmp4 = make_unique<Holder<ThingCollection>>(Holder<ThingCollection>()); // BAD.

}
```

On compiling, the final (BAD) line fails due to a copy constructor (of `unique_ptr`) being implicitly deleted.  I understand why `unique_ptr` is not copyable, but I don't understand why it wants to copy here or what the right response is.

I compiled thus:

```
clang++ -std=c++14 -pthread -Wall -Wextra -c -o mre.o mre.cc
```

Comment: *"This, of course, leads to errors about implicitly-deleted copy constructors"* - Only because you likely already implement a member function that inhibits move operations from by generated. Do you have user defined `LotsOfStuff` or `Thing` destructor? If default move operations work for you, then define `LotsOfStuff(LotsOfStuff&&) = default;`

Comment: And the fact I have to take your "of course" and guess at the "likely" cause (because it's not really "of course") kinda shows you need a proper [mre] instead of hand-waving a description of code.

Comment: I don't see a `unique_ptr` in your `Thing` class (well, you haven't actually shown us your `Thing` class), only in your `ThingCollection` class.

Comment: Would it help to make a manager of `Thing` objects and use a factory to create them. Next use `shared_ptr` to access `Thins` objects?

Comment: *"to add a `Thing` to each `LotsOfStuff`."* Do you mean `ThingCollection` instead of `Thing`?

Comment: *Obviously a unique_ptr can't manage something that itself contains a unique_ptr, at least not in any naive way* Why not? The `unique_ptr` will call destructor of the object it owns, which, in turn, calls destructors of any `unique_ptr` it contains

Comment: You are all quite right that the question sucked.  I have provided a MRE to make this concrete.

Comment: `Holder` doesn't have move constructor...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This, of course, leads to errors about implicitly-deleted copy constructors. I think I understand why this is so

You generally get such errors when you try to copy objects of a type that has non-copyable members.

Solution: Don't try to copy non-copyable objects.

---

> Disclaimer: Obviously a unique_ptr can't manage something that itself contains a unique_ptr, at least not in any naive way.

On the contrary, unique pointer can easily manage something that itself contains a unique pointer. The only case I can think of where naive approach would fail is when pointers form a recursive chain - essentially a linked list - in which case you need a custom destructor to avoid linear recursion depth.

P.S. Instead of your `ThingCollection` class, I recommend using `boost::multi_index_container`.

Comment: Thanks.  Having now read the `boost::multi_index_container` docs, this seems like the best strategy anyway: it should sort the problem I have and provide a better solution anyway.